# Turbo table: How to display the data in PrimeNG table ? Data value may contains the Json object or Array

Tags: primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am able to display as below
[image]How to display the data in PrimeNG turbo table ? Json data value may contains the Json object or array. And I want to display in proper format.
Here I am receiving the data by REST API call, and key is string but not sure which data type value is.

Ex: JSON Data is

```
{
    "data" :[
        {"key": "Description", "value": "This is controller"},
        {"key": "Name", "value": [{"key","lastName", "value", "XYZ"},
            "key","firstName", "value", "ABC"              
            ]},
        {"key": "SerialNumber", "value": ["1000", "89881"]},
        {"key": "ModelNumber", "value" : "10009WR7773"}
    ]
}
```

Note: We are receiving JSON data from rest api dynamically

[image] 
Output should be as attached screenshot

Please help me in resolving this issue, thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Antikhippe, I am able to display the key and value in the simple format.

Comment: @Antikhippe, attached the image above

Comment: Can you share a StackBlitz please ?

Comment: @Antikhippe, Please find the StackBlitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8nrqed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The above stackblitz example is just the with Json obect as above.

Comment: Have a look at [row grouping](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowgroup), it should meet your needs. Btw, your json is not valid.

Comment: @Antikhippe, My json data is a mix of value like Object, Array, String and Int. So how can i achieve this?